# Is there a potential for bias when a researcher chooses a topic they personally find interesting?

Tags: research-topic, conflict-of-interest

When choosing a research topic, many researchers (in the field of psychology, in my case) often choose to study a topic they find interesting or have experience in. Does this introduce more potential for bias in their work?

I have done this myself. I am doing research into an area that I also work in, and enjoy as a hobby. I see that this has the benefit of existing knowledge in that area, and more motivation to continue researching the topic. But to what degree is it problematic that the researcher is personally involved in their field of interest? Is there a conflict of interest when someone struggling with addiction does academic research into addiction? Does the methodology affect this? Does a qualitative researcher have less personal bias than a qualitative researcher interpreting their findings?

Comment: Think at the potential bias you would introduce in a topic that you find boring ;-)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Do you mean that the results of such a study could be wrong (biased)? If so, why?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: @massimoOrtolano haha that's a good point! But I feel a researcher can remain relatively neutral towards a field. Many people have jobs they don't love, but they still perform them effectively.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper potentially. A researcher's personal experience with a topic may bias their results with their subjective opinion on the topic. A researcher may go into a topic assuming a result from the start, for example.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist my bad, I will do so in future.

Comment: @RossKeenan Then it depends on the type of methodology. For example, in a questionnaire, one might formulate leading questions and this definitely is an issue. Normally, there are for each methodology catalogs of "threats to validity" available that help to mitigate these issues.

Comment: Is one of the "qualitative"s in the last sentence suppose to be "quantitative"?

Comment: Yes, but in an area that one has no interest in, one could be biased by making assumptions or having a lack of understanding. One needs to test the internal validity, external validity, and reliability of the measurement instrument. One also needs to setup the analysis plan at the beginning to avoid trying different analyses until you get the result you expect.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, please don't be so picky about "one question per post". Separating them here would be less than useful, and they are all aspects of the same thing.

Comment: @Buffy I see at least three completely orthogonal questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is, well, yes. But what alternative would you propose? Forcing researchers to work on topics they aren’t passionate about seems like a bad idea. Academia has few financial incentives as compared to industry. The only reason many stay is because of the freedom it affords them. Take away that, and there’s not much keeping people in it.

Keeping researchers’ biases in check is what peer review is for. Even if you happen to work on a topic you aren’t super passionate about (say, you got moderately involved in a project due to a very specific skill you bring in), you still have an incentive to publish the results, which should be kept in check regardless of personal interest.

Comment: I think the actual "yes" demands some more explanation, as some types of methodologies are certainly more prone to such bias than others.

Comment: I agree. There is potential for bias either way. But being forced to work on a topic you don’t enjoy seems unreasonable.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any bias issue in selecting interesting *questions*. But there certainly is if you choose to search out support for what you think a priori is the correct answer.

Questions, themselves, have no bias. But it is the evidence that answers the question. If any other "techniques" come in to play than honest search for truth then there is a problem.

I found that first time researchers need to be taught this lesson. I also had to assure them that  if the evidence leads to rejecting the main hypothesis that they have succeeded, not failed, since they have new evidence of what may be true.

But selecting a question or an area of study because you have some deep connection to that idea is not, in itself, any cause for alarm. In fact it can (and should) result in dedication to the task of finding truth.

Suppose someone with a medical issue of some kind decides to research that. It does them no good to fake research or bias it in the direction of anything but the truth.

Companies, on the other hand, often have a financial interest in promoting not-truth. Overstating the benefits of a particular vaccine is a particular danger at the moment. Likewise the "research" done and published and promoted by tobacco companies was/is not a search for truth, but for financial advantage, since the costs fall elsewhere.

Comment: "Questions, themselves, have no bias."  Classic counter example:  "Do you still beat your wife?"

Comment: Scientific racists (not real scientists) are skilled in asking biased questions.

Comment: Sorry, @AnonymousPhysicist, but that is an idiotic comment that has no relevance to the question or answer. Sorry that I've pissed you off again.

Comment: You have never pissed me off.  I just get slightly disappointed at worst.  I picked that example because it is well known, I agree it's not the most relevant.

Comment: This is a really good point. Someone with genuine interest in a field is _less_ likely to make false conclusions, as the findings directly affect them!

Answer (score 0):

Bias is defined as any tendency which prevents unprejudiced consideration of a question. In research, bias occurs when “systematic error [is] introduced into sampling or testing by selecting or encouraging one outcome or answer over others” .

https://bit.ly/3q4Ijzf

Selecting or encouraging one outcome or answer is scientific misconduct.

As far someone doesn't do that, they can get their otherwise biased data or give their biased interpretation of them, of course. In the best case they change mind soon or later, for what their individual opinion matters. Or the rest of the world find out they were the biased ones.

To me, a not interested individual under the pressure of the environment is perhaps more prone to actively falsify data or be "victim" of biases than a genuine enthusiast.

Of course, this refer to genuine scientific interest.

If the financial asset of a researcher, to take an extreme example, is sensitive to a result, I suspect that bias and even fraud becomes much probable.

Comment: If you called [biased data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_(statistics)) misconduct you'd pretty much have to fire every scientist.

Comment: @Libor not interested in starting a discussion on the meaning of biased data. Link is not accessible to me. I will edit my answer to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: The meaning of words is the meaning of words. You're confusing bias with fraud and they aren't synonyms - bias has a very specific meaning in the context of data.

Comment: Then ask OP in which way it intends interest as a source of bias @Libor

Comment: Bias in the context of people (as in the question and all of the other answers) is not the same as bias in the context of data. Your definition is actually getting worse, because bias in data does not in any way require an observer to have bias as a person. This is a big deal because dealing with bias in data is a pretty important topic that's only tangentially related (at most) to dealing with bias in people.

Comment: @Libor already you recognise that words might have different meaning. You were biased as for you statistical bias is the only one. IMy answer is about bias in research, and *especially* for the bias which might be introduced by the researcher. Other type of biases should not depend on the emotion or the happiness found in conducting a research.